# How to create Team Project Collections on VisualStudio.com?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, team-project

I wonder if is possible to create Project collections using visualstudio.com service.
The only collection avaliable is DefaultCollection.

Thank you,

Murilo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Team Foundation Service only allows one team project collection.  You would have to use another account to create another instance of TF service.

Comment: This is still true as of today with AzureDevOps.